# I can't install my own Application from the play store

Tags: android, flutter

I used flutter to make a small app, I publish it on the play store. Problem is, I can't install on any avd I have. I get the "your device is not compatible with this version" (or a similar message depending on the android version I tried with).

I just followed the instructions on how to make an apk and an app bundle (they both didn't work). How can I make it downloadable and usable in an play store enabled avd ?

Here is a `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale
    fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /Users/moo/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (6 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/moo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 36.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.0 (API
      24) (emulator)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't install an apk from the store written in flutter on the emulator because the ABI of the emulator is `x86`, and the apk in release mode(the mode that is on the store) can't be installed on devices with `x86` ABI.
You can't even run the application in release mode on the emulator

Comment: I tried to make an apk for x86, to no avail. Do you know why it isnt possible, while it works for react native apps, for example.

Comment: the flutter team(currently) don't provide x86 release binary support.